# default function that takes a function object and calls it - Python

Tags: python

Is there a default function or way to call a function object?

```
lambda x: x()
```

works.

It seems like `x()` is roughly equivalent to `x.__call__()`, but `__call__` is a class method rather than a function.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm dealing with a case where I have a `list` of partial functions that I want to `map()`, but they all take no arguments (arguments are already baked in).

It just *seems* like there must be a built in way to do that with a function call, but maybe not!

Comment: Huh? How does `lambda x: x()` not work?

Comment: it does work, but I'm wondering if there is a built in function or way to do it.

Comment: In Python 2.7 there was a deprecated `apply` built-in. but you probably shouldn't use it (it was deprecated in 2.3)

Comment: Better yet, just don't use `map`. Use a list-comprehension: `[f() for f in list_of_partial_functions]`

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you have a list of functions and that none of them expect any arguments, so you can simply iterate over the list and just call each function:

```
for func in list_of_functions:
    func()
```

Answer (score 2):

There *used* to be a built-in function, [`apply`, but it is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) although still available on Python 2:

```
>>> partials = [(lambda x: lambda: x)(c) for c in ['foo','bar','baz']]
>>> partials[0]()
'foo'
>>> partials[1]()
'bar'
>>> partials[2]()
'baz'
>>> map(apply, partials)
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

You should just dispence with the `map` approach altogether and use a list-comprehension, which is generally preferred over `map` + `lambda`, and will work in Python 2 and Python 3:

```
>>> [f() for f in partials]
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for this! I didn't know about the apply function, that's cool.
I have to use map because I'm actually using multiprocessing pool.map. I could use a loop there with apply_async on each. 
The full complexity I'm dealing with is that I have a list of lists of functions, the sub-list of functions needs to be called in order, but those altogether can be called in parallel. So I have
`pool.map(lambda a: [b() for b in a], list_of_lists_of_functions)`

Comment: don't use `apply` it is not cool. It is deprecated. Very uncool. I would loop with `apply_async` personally.